# Convert cell of 'True' and 'False' values to a numeric array of 1s and 0s

Tags: arrays, matlab, boolean, vectorization, cell

i have a 6432 x 1 cell containing values of either 'True' or 'False'. 
I'm trying to convert the cell to a numeric array with a value of 0 for False and 1 for True. 
I must be missing an obvious solution, but I feel like I've tried everything. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little out of the box solution, which should be faster than comparing the same strings thousands of times:

```
t = sum(char(s),2) < 485
```

### Explanation

`char(s)` makes a char-array out of the cell array of strings.

`sum` creates a checksum.

If the checksum is smaller than 500 (actually 481, to be exact), it must be `'true'`. The checksum of `'false'` is 523. For that matter, as the capital letter variant `'True'` leads to 448 and `'False'` to 491, something around **485** would be a suitable threshold value.

Comment: This is very clever!

Comment: Ok i got this to work with one small change: t = sum(char(s),2) < 480. I'm not sure why I have different checksums than you, but on my end, its 491 for False and 448 for True. Thank you!

Comment: @thymyandspace Now that you say it, Capital letters have different values, and as you have `True` and `False`, your check sums are different. For this reason  think a threshold between 481 and 491 is a good choice, as you cover both cases. With 480, you miss `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If your cell is called `s`, you can do this:

```
t = zeros(size(s));
t(strcmp(s,'True')) = 1;
```

Comment: You could also use the one-liner `t = double(strcmp(s, 'True'));`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a way that works but seems inefficient?
If anyone knows a better solution it'd be much appreciated.

```
t = find(strcmp(tad, 'True'));
tad(t,:) = {1};
f = find(strcmp(tad, 'False'));
tad(f,:) = {0}
```

Comment: You can almost always leave out `find`. The logical array that you use as input to `find` can also be used to index.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cellfun and only compare the first character for better performance (However, it may be slower for using cellfun).

`t = double(cellfun(@(x) x(1) == 'T',s));`

This is another method just for fun:

`t = 5 - cellfun(@length,s);`

or

`t = 5 - cellfun('length',s);`